# How to run a Haxe project?

Tags: haxe

I'm new to using Haxe, and I'm trying to learn from [this open source project](https://gitlab.com/dpzbusinezz/canaanrebornopensource)

I recently watched the tutorial video "introduction to Haxe helloworld" and they didn't use any `.hxml` file to compile.

If I look in `canaanreborn2020prealha > game-master`, there are several files, including a `compile.hxml`.

I know that I have to do something with it right? What are the exact steps?

Comment: This looks to me like a general Haxe programming question that [you could find answered on our general programming sister site, StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+run+haxe). Is there anything specific to game development you need help with here?

Answer (score 1):

An [HXML](https://haxe.org/manual/compiler-usage-hxml.html) file is a format which stores a list of compiler arguments. It can have any name (not just `build.hxml`) as long as it has the `.hxml` extension, and a project can have multiple `.hxml` files (which is useful for distinguishing between targets for example).

In your example, you can call the following from the command line to build the Haxe project:

```bash
haxe compile.hxml
```

Answer (score 0):

You should point [hxml file](https://haxe.org/manual/compiler-usage-hxml.html) to haxe to compile it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).